# retrieve rows which are between fromdate and enddate throws an error Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query which when I try to retrieve rows which are between fromdate and enddate throws an error on line 122.

117 :

```
$todaydate=date("Y-m-d");
```

119 :

```
$query = "select * from `tblads` where `ADApproved`=1 and `ADShow`=1 and '$todaydate' between `ADFromeDate` and `ADTillDate`";
```

120 :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

122 :

```
if ($sql->num_rows > 0) { (Getting error on this line "Trying to get property of non-object")
```

Comment: Never forget to include errors.

Comment: Use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) To find out what error your query might be failing on

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you that helped me and found that the Column name ADFromeDate was incorrect. The actual name was ADFromDate. Silly mistake caused so much time.